# Swift dismiss modal view on tableView select (best practices for control flow)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am working on a Swift application that needs to set the application scope from a tableView -- the user will select a list item which will then set an ID which controls the data loaded in other views. I am currently opening the tableView as a modal but I am not sure what is the best practice for closing the modal from within the `setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` function call of a custom tableViewCell subclass (or even if dismissing the modal from this function is the best practice). I was considering passing a reference of the parent view that loaded the modal and then using `dismissViewControllerAnimate` but that is not working.

*Edit* : my original post seemed to be unclear so I will try to clearly ask my questions:

1.) I need dismiss the modal view and the only function I have come across so far is `dismissViewControllerAnimate` -- is this the function I should be using or are there others for others uses?

2.) If `dismissViewControllerAnimate` is the correct function, should I be calling it from within the `setSelected` function of the tableViewCell?

3.) If I should call from within `setSelected`, should I pass a reference of the ViewController to the tableViewCell so that it can call `dismissViewControllerAnimate` from `setSelected`?

*/Edit*

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: please don't down-vote without explanation..

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted but your question isn't clear. Post your code and explain where your problem occurs.

Comment: this question lacks sufficient information and code, demonstrates that you did not study the basic documentation and is opinion-based.

Comment: @vikingosegundo This post is in no way opinion-based (unless you want to call best practices an "opinion", in which case, I would firmly disagree).

Comment: @vikingosegundo and you are correct about having not thoroughly studied the documentation -- I have recently picked up Swift and I am trying to work through an application as I learn it instead of learning it and then starting development so there are some tradeoffs (such as having to seek advise from those who are more experienced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to handle the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your table view controller and call dismissViewControllerAnimated from there after noting what cell was selected.

Comment: this doesnt work for me. the controller is not closed. `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        CouponHolder.instance.setCustomer(searchResults[indexPath.row]);
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }`